# update entity without reading entire entity in EF core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, updates

Is it possible to update only specific property when we have only primary key, I don't want to read existing complete entity. I think it can be done by
as below

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "Update Book SET Name='WhatEver' WHERE id=@id";
    var name = new SqlParameter("@id", "10001");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
}
```

But are there any way to update without using SQL query in EF core?

Note: Typical way

1. Read existing Book entity
2. Update the Name
   3  then savechanges

But, When we need to update 20k records this typical way is more expensive

Comment: Use a tool like Linq2db.

Answer (score 1):

EF isn't really suited to batch operations, though it is a tool in the toolbelt so when faced with a requirement that doesn't suit a power drill it's perfectly fine to pull out a screwdriver for more fine-tuned control.

If you need to perform a bulk update such as updating a status or date, or some other static change across a large number of rows, there is nothing wrong with scripting it up as a statement and executing it across the Database with ExecuteSqlCommand. The catch here is that if any of these records happen to be tracked entities in the DbContext you might be using, you will need to flush these and reload them from the database after executing the command to see the changes.

If you need to perform a logic check on a large number of rows and would prefer to do that in code rather than something like SQL or a Sproc, then another option is to use a scoped DbContext with a minimalist entity definition, load the entities in batches and save them. For instance if you have an entity that consists of 100 columns excluding relationships and you only need 4 columns to cover what you need to inspect and update, then you can define a DbContext for handling the update with an entity definition with just those four columns. These can be read in batches of rows, i.e. 1000-10000 at a time from the update DbContext, then fed into a method to validate & update before calling `SaveChanges()`, then dumping and recreating the DbContext instance for the next batch. The caveat with this approach is transactional in that if an update fails, only that batch would be rolled back. Because of the smaller entity footprint the system could potentially manage updating a much larger number of entities in one go, possibly all entities, but this would need to be monitored for performance cost. Bulk operations might be best scheduled for after-hours whenever possible to avoid causing read locks / deadlocks or heavy transactional operations on the database if they could be triggered ad-hoc during busy periods.